# Referencing bundles/controllers/files changed in Symfony2.2?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

I understand this: http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/configuration/twig.html (version 2.1) and how to reference a bundle for exception_controller:

```
exception_controller:  Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::showAction
```

But I don't understand how to do it for version 2.2 (which I'm using) (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html)

```
exception_controller:  twig.controller.exception:showAction
```

My bundle is located at:

```
Acme\Bundle\MyBundle\Controller\MyController::runAction
```

...how do I reference it in 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just have to use the underscore notation:

```
acme_my.controller.my:runAction
```

if your bundle is defined as `AcmeMyBundle`. So if I have a AcmeUserBundle and using the controller `ExceptionController` I would something like this:

```
acme_user.controller.exception:debugAction
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work and I've found that twig.controller.exception is reference to a service